# Are Ethereum Smart Contracts a Viable Way to Invest in New Companies?

Tags: investing

A relation's company is thinking of going with [Neufund](https://neufund.org/), and use their guidance in order to develop smart contracts for investors to invest in their company.

1. Does anyone have experience with this?
2. Anyone have opinions on the matter?
3. If one (as a developer) wants to start developing Ethereum smart contracts today, for instance for an IPO type thing, where does one begin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I need an investment in my coin-op car wash to add a compressed air terminal.  You come to me and say I'd love to invest, here's a bag of diamonds.  I can't spend diamonds.  You respond to me, don't worry it's on a smart contract so our agreement enforces itself and diamonds might go up in value too!!  But I need an air terminal.

A company that needs investment needs something it can spend.  It really doesn't matter how fancy the tech that delivers the capital is if I can't use it to install a compressed air terminal which is why I needed the capital in the first place.  And your smart contract won't do much if I gut the account when I convert your tokens in to something I can actually spend.

There's a practical disconnect that exists with crypto starting primarily with the fact that they, largely, can't be spent right now.

Notwithstanding the fact that you'll need a serious bankroll to manage the regulatory hammer that will come looking for you if you achieve any degree of real success underwriting any sort of security issue with a smart contract.

And YOU should be verrrry wary of a company that is looking for your bag of diamonds when it says it needs a compressed air terminal.

Comment: To use your metaphor, as I understand it, it is rather the scenario that I want to invest in your car wash (with dollars, not any blockchain coins) and in return you give me a share in it via smart contracts or Ethereum. So this would be a way to bypass the regulatory overhead of an actual IPO but still having some guarantee for the buyer (using smart contracts and not official legalized contracts), but maybe I'm wrong. What do you think of that?

Comment: Refer to paragraph 4.

Comment: Can you give me a real life example of one such regulatory hammering that could occur?

Comment: What I'm saying is the wild wild west days of crypto are numbered, getting involved in facilitating unregistered public offerings is something I'd avoid unless your intent is to set the legal precedent.

Comment: @PointoSenshi , see this article for example: [The SEC's Big Digital Coin Ruling: What It Means](http://fortune.com/2017/07/26/sec-icos/).